# Identify if the post author is a page or a user?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

What is the proper way to identify if the author of a post is a user or a page?

`v2.8/OrangeESP/feed?fields=id,from{id,name,link}`

```
"data": [
{
  "id": "118067454874491_1584993008181921",
  "from": {
    "id": "1112315252115029",
    "name": "Clara Barranquero",
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1112315252115029/"
  }
},
```

I currently use the "from.link" for that and if it is of form

*https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id//* then is a User

if it's of from

*https://www.facebook.com/* then it is a Page

In v2.4 I could have included from{category} in the response and if that was not empty it meant the author is a Page.

Answer (score 0):

Include a field that´s only available in the Page or User table:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Checking for `app_scoped_user_id` in the link field is not a bad idea though.

Comment: If I include "from.category" which is only available in Page table I get an error:

`/v2.8/orangeesp/feed?fields=from{category}

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (category) on node type (User)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "BVnRd6YHc7Y"
  }
}
`

Comment: i would just use the app_scoped_user_id anyway, it´s not a bad idea.